# Why file name and string are not equal?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I try to know contains my S3 bucket file with some name.

This is the snippet of my code:

```
  this.s3Client.listObjects(params)
  .promise()
  .then(data => {
    this.isConverting = false
    console.info(data)

    for (let file of data.Contents.values()) {
      console.info(file.Key)
      console.info("fileName: " + fileName)
      console.info(file.toString() === fileName)
      console.info(typeof file.toString())
      console.info(typeof fileName)
      if (file.toString()=== fileName) {
        this.isConverting = false
        this.downloadFile(fileName)
      }
    }
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

In console I see this:

[image]

**Why test_4.epub isn't equal to test_4.epub?**

Comment: Try adding `console.info(file.toString()` somewhere.

Comment: change `console.info(file.Key)` to `console.info(file.toString())`

Comment: Because file.toString() is not the same as file.Key.  file is some kind of object.  You probably are wanting to compare file.key to fileName, not file.toString().

Comment: Or change `file.toString() == fileName` to `file.Key === fileName`.